# Are Windows Precision Touchpad click/tap events communicated through the WM_INPUT message? If not, how do I get them?

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, hid

I'm in the middle of adding custom Windows Touchpad handling into my Windows C++ desktop application. From a high level, the app has its own cursor and objects that can be clicked. The cursor needs to be directly controlled by a Windows Precision Touchpad, and completely decoupled from the standard Windows mouse. I'm accomplishing this via processing raw input from WM_INPUT messages, and using low level mouse hooks to prevent controlling the normal mouse pointer.

I'm able to interpret single and multi-finger gestures just fine using the WM_INPUT data, but haven't figured out how to get "clicks" or "taps" from the touchpad. [Legacy Mouse Input](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/mouse-input) events will obviously not work for my use case since they:

1. Aren't global and require my app to be focused
2. Are generated by any connected mouse/pointing device, not just the touchpad I registered for.
3. Interact at the location of the Windows mouse pointer, which is not driving the cursor in my app.

Are clicks/taps contained in the WM_INPUT reports, and I'm just not able to find them, or is there another way I can capture raw clicks from *only* the touchpad in my application?

Comment: I believe Raw Input really just observes the raw input events (e.g. a finger touching the digitizer, the contact area covered, etc.). Higher-level semantics (like clicks or long presses) aren't available.

Answer (score 4):

[RAWMOUSE](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/win32/api/winuser/ns-winuser-rawmouse) struct that comes with `WM_INPUT` mouse message contains `usButtonFlags` with mouse button up/down transition state.

You cannot get clicks/taps because AFAIK classic Win32 API is not suitable for touch input at all - it just emulating mouse in case of touchpad.

According to [touchpad spec](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows-hardware/design/component-guidelines/touchpad-windows-precision-touchpad-collection) all compatible `Windows Precision Touchpad`'s are HID devices that are sending touchpad data in their `Input Reports`. They should contain corresponding Top Level Collection `Page 0x0D` (Digitizers), `Usage 0x05` (Touch Pad) - and this will be seen as separate HID device from Win32 user-mode. See sample [HID Report Descriptor](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows-hardware/design/component-guidelines/windows-precision-touchpad-sample-report-descriptors).

Knowing this you can register to receive touchpad data with `RegisterRawInputDevices` call. After that you'll receive `WM_INPUT` message with [RAWHID](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/win32/api/winuser/ns-winuser-rawhid) struct for each [tounchpad input report](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows-hardware/design/component-guidelines/windows-precision-touchpad-required-hid-top-level-collections#windows-precision-touchpad-input-reports) - this needs to be handled manually (according to device's [Preparsed HID Report Descriptor Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/hid/preparsed-data) etc).

It's not easy but doable.

See [example code here](https://github.com/ichisadashioko/windows-touchpad).

**Update**: Also there are [WM_TOUCH](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/win32/wintouch/wm-touchdown) and [WM_GESTURE](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/win32/wintouch/wm-gesture) messages available since Windows 7. Maybe its [what you're looking for](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/win32/wintouch/windows-touch-programming-reference). [Sample code](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/tree/main/Samples/Win7Samples/Touch/MTGestures/cpp).

Comment: Rich support for touch input was added in WinRT API - https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/apps/design/input/touch-interactions
There you can handle events like touch, tap, zoom, swipe, stretch etc

Answer (score 0):

you can use `PostMessage(applicationWinhandle, WM_INPUT, wparam, mouseDeviceHandle)` send `WM_INPUT` message to your application, and then hook `GetRawInputData` or `GetRawInputBuffer` to send data.